# Wordpress Plugin add_meta_box to functions.php instead of inside plugin class

Tags: php, class, wordpress

I'm using a Wordpress plugin that adds a metabox to the post page via

```
add_meta_box( 'WPInsights', 'Insights', array(&$this,'draw_insights'), 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
```

I want to add a meta box the same way through my `functions.php` file, but it says the first argument is supposed to be a valid callback (I assume it is referring to the use of `&$this` because `WPInsights` is a class and `draw_insights()` is a function inside that class.

How can I write an `add_meta_box` function for my `functions.php` file that uses the `WPInsights` class?

Answer (score 1):

Hook into the action `add_meta_boxes` like this:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', array(get_class(), 'draw_insights'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function does not function the same say the [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) function.  The add_action reference states that it takes a callback but the add_meta_box function states that it takes a string that it uses as a callback.  While the argument is named 'callback' it does not state that it will take any php callback as the add_action one does.